# Google Admob Approval Issue

Tags: admob, adsense

I have created two admob account with same IP and device but different Gmail account , however one admob account was canceled and gmail payment profile was deleted . The problem is that my another admob account was not get approved , what should i do now??

I canceled one account and deleted Gmail payment profile of one the created account